# how to merge multiple column data into two columns in SPSS and/or excel?

Tags: excel, spss

I am learning data input in SPSS and excel. For example, I have 500 column data format below:

```
plant1  plant2  plant3  …   plant500
-0.32   -0.01   -0.28   …   …
-0.40   0.14    -0.19   …   …
-0.43   -0.19   -0.29   …   …
-0.48   -0.16   -0.04   …   …
```

I want to change it to format below:

```
plant1   -0.32 
plant1   -0.40 
plant1   -0.43 
plant1   -0.48 
plant2   -0.01 
plant2   0.14 
plant2  -0.19 
plant2  -0.16 
plant3  -0.28 
plant3  -0.19 
plant3  -0.29 
plant3  -0.04 
…           …
plant500    …
plant500    …
plant500    …
plant500    …
```

Can you help me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into problems? This is an **UNPIVOT** operation and there are plenty of examples on this forum showing how to accomplish it.  It might help you to word your question by reading the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm sure powerquery in Excel can do this in a few clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SPSS, assuming your `plant1` to `plant500` variables are consecutive, the below syntax will do the trick; (if your variables are not consecutive, you will have to specify them one by one).

`VARSTOCASES
/MAKE reading from plant1 to plant500
/INDEX=PLANT_NR (reading).
EXECUTE.`

Here is more on the `VARSTOCASES` command:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_varstocases_variable_name_index.html